# getting values from input and using them as varibale names in javascript for predifned varible values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get a string from the input convert it to array and use the vales provided to replace the string with variable value to create an array from values.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const a= 1,j=1,s=1;
  const b=2,k=2,t=2;
  const c=3,l=3,u=3;
  const d=4,m=4,v=4;
  const e=5,n=5,w=5;
  const f=6, o=6,x=6;
  const g=7,p=7,y=7;
  const h=8,q=8,z=8;
  const i=9, r=9;
  let obj = {};
  let target = "";
  let targetArray = [];
  let valArray = [];

  $("#target").keyup(function () {
    target = $("#target").val();
    for(let i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
      targetArray = Array.from(target);
      val = targetArray[i];
      //statement to get string from above to convert to values provided at top
      console.log(valArray)
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: use an object with those properties and values, instead of variables. Should make it easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone mentioned using an object to store these values instead, and I would definitely take that advice under consideration. In the meantime, you can set a property on the `window` object to make it a global variable, i.e.:

```js
const setGlobal = (name, value) => window[name] = value;

setGlobal('myVariable', 1000);
console.log(myVariable);
```

For your use case, you need to move the `const` declarations to global scope so you can set them from inside your function, and you need to use `var` instead. Then we just map `targetArray` to `window[x]` for `x` in `targetArray`.

```js
var a= 1,j=1,s=1;
var b=2,k=2,t=2;
var c=3,l=3,u=3;
var d=4,m=4,v=4;
var e=5,n=5,w=5;
var f=6, o=6,x=6;
var g=7,p=7,y=7;
var h=8,q=8,z=8;
var i=9, r=9;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#target").keyup(function() {
  
    let target = $("#target").val(),
        targetArray = Array.from(target),
        valArray = targetArray.map(x => window[x]);
        
    console.log(valArray);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="target"></textarea>
```

Note that you will need to use `window[x.toLowerCase()]` if you want to be able to handle uppercase values in the input field.